# rabbitmq kubernetes with NFS mount

Tags: nfs, kubernetes, rabbitmq, chown

I tried to set up a rabbitmq cluster in a kubernetes envirnoment that has NFS PVs with the help of [this tutorial](https://notallaboutcode.blogspot.com/2017/09/rabbitmq-on-kubernetes-container.html). Unfortunately it seems like the rabbitmq wants to change the owner of `/usr/lib/rabbitmq`, but when I have a NFS directory mounted there, I get an error:

```
 $ kubectl logs rabbitmq-0 -f
chown: /var/lib/rabbitmq: Operation not permitted
chown: /var/lib/rabbitmq: Operation not permitted
```

I guess I have two options: fork the rabbitmq and remove the [chown](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/e58e2d5ba7fd4e4a8047f45837060da901a06fde/3.8/alpine/Dockerfile#L179) and build my own images or make kubernetes/nfs work nicely. I would not like to make my own fork and getting kubernetes/nfs working nicely does not sound like it should be my problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please see https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html and https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/rabbitmq-users/CAGcLz6V4af9_TNU4HSH9x5eKEgXDKqeQ3%3DBL%2Br%3DR%2B%3DM8ghwR0Q%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Answer (score 2):

This is what i tried to reproduce this issue. I have installed kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm` on redhat 7 and below is the cluster, node details.

**ENVIRONMENT DETAILS:**

```
[root@master tmp]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use `kubectl cluster-info dump`.

***[root@master tmp]***

```
[root@master tmp]# kubectl get no
NAME         STATUS     ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master.k8s   Ready      master   8d      v1.16.2
node1.k8s    Ready   <none>   7d22h   v1.16.3
node2.k8s    Ready      <none>   7d21h   v1.16.3
[root@master tmp]#
```

First I have set the `nfs` configuration on both master and worker nodes by running below steps on both master and worker nodes. Here master node is `nfs` server and both worker nodes are `nfs` clients.

**NFS SETUP:**

```
yum install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server,client
yum install portmap       =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server,client
mkdir /nfsroot =============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>on nfs server
[root@master ~]# cat /etc/exports   =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server
/nfsroot 192.168.56.5/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/nfsroot 192.168.56.6/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
exportfs -r               =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server
service nfs start =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server,client
showmount -e =============================================================>>>>> on nfs server,client
```

Now `nfs` setup is ready and will apply `rabbitmq` k8s setup.

**RABBITMQ K8S SETUP:**

First step is to create `persistent volumes` using the `nfs mount` which we created in previous step.

```
[root@master tmp]# cat /root/rabbitmq-pv.yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: rabbitmq-pv-1
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 - ReadOnlyMany
 nfs:
  server: 192.168.56.4
  path: /nfsroot
 capacity:
  storage: 1Mi
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: rabbitmq-pv-2
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 - ReadOnlyMany
 nfs:
  server: 192.168.56.4
  path: /nfsroot
 capacity:
  storage: 1Mi
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: rabbitmq-pv-3
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 - ReadOnlyMany
 nfs:
  server: 192.168.56.4
  path: /nfsroot
 capacity:
  storage: 1Mi
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: rabbitmq-pv-4
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
 - ReadOnlyMany
 nfs:
  server: 192.168.56.4
  path: /nfsroot
 capacity:
  storage: 1Mi
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

After applied the above manifest, it created `pv's` as below:

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl apply -f rabbitmq-pv.yaml
persistentvolume/rabbitmq-pv-1 created
persistentvolume/rabbitmq-pv-2 created
persistentvolume/rabbitmq-pv-3 created
persistentvolume/rabbitmq-pv-4 created
[root@master ~]# kubectl get pv
NAME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
rabbitmq-pv-1   1Mi        RWO,ROX        Recycle          Available                                   5s
rabbitmq-pv-2   1Mi        RWO,ROX        Recycle          Available                                   5s
rabbitmq-pv-3   1Mi        RWO,ROX        Recycle          Available                                   5s
rabbitmq-pv-4   1Mi        RWO,ROX        Recycle          Available                                   5s
[root@master ~]#
```

No need to create `PersistentVolumeClaim` ,since it will be automatically taken care while running `statefulset` manifest by `volumeclaimtemplate` option. Now lets create the `secret` which you have mentioned as below:

```
[root@master tmp]# kubectl create secret generic rabbitmq-config --from-literal=erlang-cookie=c-is-for-cookie-thats-good-enough-for-me
secret/rabbitmq-config created
[root@master tmp]#

[root@master tmp]# kubectl get secrets
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-vjsmd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      8d
jp-token-cfdzx        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      5d2h
rabbitmq-config       Opaque                                1      39m
[root@master tmp]#
```

Now let submit your `rabbitmq` manifest by make changes of replacing all `loadbalancer` service type to `nodeport` service, since we are not using any cloudprovider environment. Also replace the `volume names` to rabbitmq-pv, which we have created in pv step. Reduced the size from 1Gi to 1Mi, since it is just testing demo.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # Expose the management HTTP port on each node
  name: rabbitmq-management
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 15672
    name: http
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The required headless service for StatefulSets
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 4369
    name: epmd
  - port: 25672
    name: rabbitmq-dist
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The required headless service for StatefulSets
  name: rabbitmq-cluster
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    name: amqp
  - port: 4369
    name: epmd
  - port: 25672
    name: rabbitmq-dist
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  serviceName: "rabbitmq"
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: rabbitmq
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3.6.6-management-alpine
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - >
                if [ -z "$(grep rabbitmq /etc/resolv.conf)" ]; then
                  sed "s/^search \([^ ]\+\)/search rabbitmq.\1 \1/" /etc/resolv.conf > /etc/resolv.conf.new;
                  cat /etc/resolv.conf.new > /etc/resolv.conf;
                  rm /etc/resolv.conf.new;
                fi;
                until rabbitmqctl node_health_check; do sleep 1; done;
                if [[ "$HOSTNAME" != "rabbitmq-0" && -z "$(rabbitmqctl cluster_status | grep rabbitmq-0)" ]]; then
                  rabbitmqctl stop_app;
                  rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbitmq-0;
                  rabbitmqctl start_app;
                fi;
                rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "." '{"ha-mode":"exactly","ha-params":3,"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
        env:
        - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbitmq-config
              key: erlang-cookie
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        - containerPort: 25672
          name: rabbitmq-dist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-pv
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: rabbitmq-pv
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Mi # make this bigger in production
```

After submitted the manifest, we are able to see `statefulset` and pods were created.

```
[root@master tmp]# kubectl apply -f rabbitmq.yaml
service/rabbitmq-management created
service/rabbitmq created
service/rabbitmq-cluster created
statefulset.apps/rabbitmq created

[root@master tmp]#
NAME                         READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-0                   1/1     Running                      0          18m
rabbitmq-1                   1/1     Running                      0          17m
rabbitmq-2                   1/1     Running                      0          13m
rabbitmq-3                   1/1     Running                      0          13m

[root@master ~]# kubectl get pvc
NAME                     STATUS   VOLUME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
rabbitmq-pv-rabbitmq-0   Bound    rabbitmq-pv-1   1Mi        RWO,ROX                       49m
rabbitmq-pv-rabbitmq-1   Bound    rabbitmq-pv-3   1Mi        RWO,ROX                       48m
rabbitmq-pv-rabbitmq-2   Bound    rabbitmq-pv-2   1Mi        RWO,ROX                       44m
rabbitmq-pv-rabbitmq-3   Bound    rabbitmq-pv-4   1Mi        RWO,ROX                       43m

[root@master ~]# kubectl get svc
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                         AGE
rabbitmq              ClusterIP   None             <none>        5672/TCP,4369/TCP,25672/TCP                     49m
rabbitmq-cluster      NodePort    10.102.250.172   <none>        5672:30574/TCP,4369:31757/TCP,25672:31854/TCP   49m
rabbitmq-management   NodePort    10.108.131.46    <none>        15672:31716/TCP                                 49m
[root@master ~]#
```

Now I've tried to hit the `rabbitmq` management page using `nodeport` service by http://192.168.56.6://31716 and I was able to get the login page `rabbitmq` management.

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsUZG.png)

cluster status

So please let me know if you still face chown issue after you tried like above, so that we can see further by checking `podsecuritypolicies` applied or not.